# Comprobar registro siguiente BD (Vb.Net)

Tags: sql, vb.net, lista

Os expongo mi duda, tengo una aplicación Vb.net, en la que un label marca una condición de 1 u 2, si es 1, inserto un registro en un campo de una BD que tenga un campo ocupado=0, pero si es 2, necesito que busque dos campos contiguos con el campo ocupado=0 y que inserte la misma información en los dos campos.

El formato de los campos es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesitaría que me buscase los dos primeros campos contiguos que tengan ocupado=0.

Llevo un tiempo dándole vueltas y no se como hacerlo

Comment: Pon alguna consulta de las que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte

Comment: solo necesitas una consultas que busque los dos primeros campos con valor 0 en todos los registro?

o necesitas buscar los 2 primeros campos que contengan 0 dado alguna otra condicion?

Answer (score 0):

Si al final de cuenta lo que necesitas son los dos primeros de tu seleccion podrias utilizar un TOP como lo muestro a continuacion

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM TABLA WHERE ocupado = 0
```

Espero te ayude y marques como util.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta que el campo es alfanumérico te adjunto la siguiente solución.

```
SELECT TOP 1 PB.NOM_HUECO,PB2.NOM_HUECO
FROM TABLA PB
INNER JOIN TABLA PB2 
ON PB2.NOM_HUECO = 'A'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUBSTRING(PB.NOM_HUECO,2,10)+1)
WHERE PB.OCUPADO = '0' AND PB2.OCUPADO = '0'
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda!